# Flutter Shake Error: 'No implementation found for method setAccelerationSamplingPeriod on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/sensors/method'

Tags: flutter

I think I'm having the issue described in [this][1] forum. I recently added the `shake` package to my Flutter app. Although it was working fine the first couple times I ran it, now it does not start most of the time because it throws this `MissingPluginException`:

```
'No implementation found for method setAccelerationSamplingPeriod on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/sensors/method'
```

When I add the dependency on `sensors_plus ^4.0.2` as suggested in the forum, I get this error:

```
Because shake 2.2.0 depends on sensors_plus ^1.4.1 and no versions of shake match >2.2.0 <3.0.0, shake ^2.2.0 requires sensors_plus ^1.4.1.
So, because dice depends on both shake ^2.2.0 and sensors_plus ^4.0.2, version solving failed.


You can try one of the following suggestions to make the pubspec resolve:
* Consider downgrading your constraint on shake: flutter pub add shake:^1.0.1
* Consider downgrading your constraint on sensors_plus: flutter pub add sensors_plus:^1.4.1
```

A later post in the forum recommends using `dependency_overrides` to satisfy the errors.

Any thoughts on the best way to tackle this issue?

Thanks!
Anson
[1]: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2471

Comment: For now I just downgraded the shake package and it seems to be playing a bit nicer, but I'd love to discuss how to do this better in the future.